# How to setup the CORS configuration in keycloak to allow an ajax request?

Tags: angular, cors, keycloak

I am trying to use keycloak as an authentication server.
I try to get the token with an ajax request. It works fine in curl but not in my angular due to CORS.
I have set the client to Direct access grant enable to true and I have added * to Web Origin.

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token", {
  body: "grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli&username=adrien&password=adrien&undefined=",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*,application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    Dnt: "1",
    "Postman-Token": "cfd33776-882d-4850-b2e7-d66629da3826"
  },
  method: "POST"
})
```

Do you know what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are trying it to use it in the wrong way. There is plugin for angular and i think you should use it. So here are the clifnotes. Install the plugin:

```
npm i keycloak-angular
```

then initialize the keycloack:

```
import {KeycloakService} from 'keycloak-angular';

export function initializer(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<any> {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        await keycloak.init({
          config: {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
            realm: 'MySecureRealm',
            clientId: 'myAngularApplication'
          },
          initOptions: {
            onLoad: 'login-required',
            checkLoginIframe: false,
            responseMode: 'fragment',
            flow: 'standard'
          }
        });
        resolve();
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  };
}
```

and then in app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule} from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {KeycloakService} from 'keycloak-angular';
import {initializer} from '../environments/environment';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TokenInterceptor} from './token-interceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    KeycloakService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializer,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

you will also need this TokenInterceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';

import { KeycloakService, KeycloakAuthGuard, KeycloakAngularModule } from 'keycloak-angular';
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http/src/headers';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(protected keycloak: KeycloakService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return Observable
      .fromPromise(this.keycloak.getToken())
      .mergeMap(
      token => {

        console.log('adding heder to request');
        console.log(token);

        const headers: HttpHeaders = req.headers;
        const hedersWithAuthorization: HttpHeaders = headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer ' + token);
        const requestWithAuthorizationHeader = req.clone({ headers: hedersWithAuthorization });
        return next.handle(requestWithAuthorizationHeader);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And that should do it. When you enter application and you are not logged in you will be redirected to the keycloak login screen and the back to your app. And to all outgoing request will be added the authentication header. Let me know if you have nay trouble I know the technology quite well.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but in your solution, the keycloak login page is used. For my use case, I want to use my own login form and then call keycloak via the rest api to retrieve the token. Maybe it is not possible, and the only recommended way is to use the keycloak login page

Comment: It is possible but it is hard to do. You have to implement whole OpenIDConnect flow in your app. If you want I can help you with that.  But I do not recommend it. Setting the fact that it might be insecure (you app will have access to username and password) it will take some time. Can you tell me why you can't use keycloak the way it is meant to be used? As delegated authorization provider?

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the explanation, I will use the keycloak login page. I have no valid reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For another person that doesn't want to use the keycloak login page, Add `http://localhost:{angularPort}` to web origins in keycloak. i.e `http://localhost:4200` not `http://localhost:4200/*`

This answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76976007/8152868

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34901373)

Comment: You make a valid point. I've done the edits