# keycloak-angular: Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, cors, keycloak

I am developing an web app and I am using angular for front-end and keycloak for security.

I am using the following packages on angular side:

**keycloak-js@10.0.1**

**keycloak-angular@8.0.1**

On front-end (angular app) I am trying to retrieve the user details using the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JwtDecoderService {

  public profile;      
  
  getUserProfile(){
  
   this.keycloakService.loadUserProfile().then(x => this.profile = x)
 
  }           
  constructor(public keycloakService: KeycloakService) {}        
}
```

As I think, the call to the **loadUserProfile()** initiates a GET request to a client (account) of the keycloak server.

I get a CORS error message as a response, see below:

[image]

I have tried to add localhost:4200 as Web Origins for the clients used, the client configured as mine on angular part is newClient, nevertheless the above request is targeting the account client.

In the end I put * as web origin for all clients involved both newClient and account.

Here are my list of clients:

[image]

As I mentioned this is the client I have indicated in angular:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  keycloakConfig: {
    clientId: 'newClient',
    realm: 'SportEmploy',
    url: 'http://localhost:8083/auth'
  }
};
```

**newClient configuration:**
1.
[image]

2.
[image]

**account client configuration:**
1.
[image]

2.
[image]

I have tried to put into WebOrigins of the both clients variations of
http://localhost:4200/  http://localhost:4200  http://localhost:4200/* **+**  and * , anything of this did not work.

This is how I start keycloak on angular side:

```
import {KeycloakService, KeycloakOptions} from 'keycloak-angular'
import { environment } from './environments/environment'

export function initializer(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<any> {

    const options: KeycloakOptions = {
      
        config: environment.keycloakConfig
    };

    return (): Promise<any> => keycloak.init(options);

}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong in my keycloak config ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but given that I had the same issue and I found the fix, I'd like to share it here for the ages.

If you set the role `account/viewProfile` to your users
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXUhm.png) the cors error will fade away.

I've opened a JIRA https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-18523 for this fyi

Answer (score 0):

Use the implicit flow for Keycloak instead of default authorization-code

```
keycloak.init({
...
initOptions: {
      flow: 'implicit',
}
}
```

and Access Type option to Public

Comment: Hi, where should I apply these changes ?

Comment: `keycloakConfig: {
    clientId: 'newClient',
    realm: 'SportEmploy',
    url: 'http://localhost:8083/auth',
    flow: 'implicit'
  }`

did not work like this

Answer (score 0):

Add http://localhost:{angularPort} to web origins in keycloak.
i.e http://localhost:4200 not http://localhost:4200/*